# can you help me to solve this function of prime numbers?

Tags: java

"The first 5 prime numbers ending in 1 are: 11, 31, 41, 61, 71

Write a program to calculate the first 5000 prime numbers ending in 9.
You can use any common programming language like, C, C++, Java, C#, Python etc."

```js
public class nbrPremier {
public static void main(String[] args) {
int reste;
boolean flag = true;
int n = 0, 5000;
for(int i=2; i <= n/2; i++)
{
//nombre est divisible par lui-meme
reste = n%i;
//si le reste est 0, alors arrete la boucle. Sinon continuer la boucle
if(reste == 0)
{
flag = false;
break;
}
}
//si flag est true, alors nombre est premier, sinon non premier
if(flag)
System.out.println(n+ " est un nombre premier");
else
System.out.println(n + " n'est pas un nombre premier");
```

The problem is how can I know the number finished by 9 or not?

Comment: Snippets only work with HTML, CSS and JS. Adding Java to them does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is how can I know the number finished by 9 or not?

`n % 10 == 9` will determine whether the remainder, when divided by 10, is 9 - i.e. whether the last digit of `n` was 9.

In the more general case you could take the string representation and check whether the last character is `'9'`, but that is clunkier and not needed here.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (n%10 == 9)
  System.out.println("This number ends in 9");
else
  System.out.println("This number does not end in 9");
```

Comment: Question asks about prime numbers ending in 9.